# Is there a name for graphs which contain oriented and non-oriented edges?

Tags: graphs, terminology

Is there a name for graphs which contain oriented and non-oriented edges?

I couldn't find on the internet if there exist a specific name for such graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called [mixed graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_graph).

Answer (score 1):

[Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) ​ (Nothing stops them from having *both* $\langle u,v\rangle$ *and* $\langle v,u\rangle$ as edges.)

Comment: Ricky means that the usual convention is to think of undirected graphs as directed graphs in which each undirected edge $\{u,v\}$ corresponds to two directed edges $\langle u,v \rangle, \langle v,u \rangle$, and you can use this correspondence for mixed graphs as well.